# Build Library Management System only using MySQL Stored Procedure with Java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I am thinking to use only Stored Procedures while developing Library Management System in Java with MySQL. But some articles show that only using Stored Procedures is an expensive method, due to the metadata retrieval that the driver performs to support output parameters. So, performance reason it is not recommended. Just use queries in your developments.

So, is it recommended to use only stored Proedures or not?

Strong reasons with logics are welcomed!

Comment: If you want to cut java out of the equation, why use java at all?  Use a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is right that there is performance issue of stored procedure so if you want to developed "online public access library catalog" (OPAC), better to use queries but if your application is to be used only in your organization stored procedure will help you to get rid of massive queries.